# what is big-O in hamming distance?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

I've implemented code in MATLAB that similar to hamming distance. for input i have one matix .I want to apply my formula that use hamming distance. my formula like this:

way is Considers two row(x,y) and apply formula. |x-y| is hamming distance two row. and then obtain max item-item of these row. like

```
x=(1,0.3 , 0 )
y=(0 , 0.1, 1)
```

for every two row of matrix obtain S,
cod is in matlab :

```
for j=1:4
 x=fin(j,:)
for i=j+1:5
 y=fin(i,:)

 s1= 1-hamming1
 end
 end
```

my question is : what is complexity or big-o in my code and formula?
what is complexity hamming distance?

Comment: Please proofread your question - there are far too many typos.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is linear in the product of lengths of `x` and `y` - `O(len(x)*len(y))` - as indicated by the double sum.

Note, however, that it is very hard to be absolutely sure because of so many typos in your question, as well as hard-coded constants in your code (which, technically, make the algorithm complexity constant).

Comment: thank you. so if my matrix is 5*4 complexity is : 5(4*4) or 4*5? do you know what is hamming complexity?

Comment: Algorithmic complexity is an asymptotic notion. It does not make sense to ask about complexity for a specific inputs.

Comment: Complexity is absolutely not an asymptotic notion. It totally makes sense to ask for the complexity of the specific input, although the formulation "5*4 complexity matrix" doesn't mean anything. It is not so frequent but still common to ask for the number of operations needed to compute f(42), given an function f. The Big O notation is asymptotic ! If your complexity is in big O, it doesn't make sense to calculate it for a specific value. Since almost everyone writes complexity using it, people think that complexity is asymptotic, but it is not.

Comment: @double_squeeze  and sds thank you for your Guidance. i mean that big O. like cosine similarity's big O is O(n^2). i want to know waht is big O hamming distance or big O my formula?

Comment: anybody could give me an answer?

Comment: @sima412: what is your question?